# what is COB Environment?

Tags: database, server, environment

I often come across terms like COB Server or COB Database. Can anyone please explain what is COB environment and how is it different from production or UAT environment.

Comment: coordination of benefits? There's far too many TLAs (three-letter acronyms) to know what you're talking about...

Comment: Never heard of it, it's possible that it is an internal term where you work... I've seen loads of those

Comment: I'm still not sure if it is specific to our company or not, but got to know that COB environment is a production like environment and if production environment is down then it is pointed to this environment.

Comment: It is not your term in your company. Check the answer of @Carlos Negan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found this, I think is useful to have it in mind. Cheers!

Dev-> Development environment. Only used for coding and developers can access.

SIT-> Software Integration Test environment, Integration test group that verifies initial integration tests, (not functionality test) should be application managers or technology project testers. Also may be developers but not preferred.

UAT-> User Acceptance Test environment. Functionality test, is done by dedicated UAT groups or end users. Environment should be identical with production env. Developers or other technology staff should not access to UAT. Only functionality testers have access.

COB-> Continuity Of Business environment for disaster recovery. Highly advised to be identical with production environment. Also user rights/access should be identical with prod. Also first production release may be tested here before actual prod implementation with an appropriate change management process.

Prod-> Production environment. Final release, after UAT approvals received and an appropriate change management process, release can be implemented here by dedicated implementers.

Answer (score 2):

COB environment is a production like environment and if production environment is down then it is pointed to this environment